# Assigning Javascript array to variable is causing items to drop from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, local-storage

I am experiencing a weird problem where assigning an array to a variable is causing some of the items in the array to be removed. This could potentially be related to Vue.js as well.

I am storing an array of data in localStorage as a string ( since that is all localStorage accepts ). When the user clicks a button within the app it runs a Vue function checking to see if localStorage has a particular key and if so I am assigning that key to a variable 'localCards' within the function. When the localStorage data gets assigned to the variable it is dropping some of the items in the array. Below is a sample of the code for a better understanding:

```
console.log( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localCards')) );
// Returns the complete array
```

```
let localCards = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localCards'));
console.log( localCards );
// Returns the first two items in the array
```

Any idea why assigning the data to a variable is dropping some of the items?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? This is not enough information to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Assigning it to a local variable won't drop items. Objects/arrays logged to the console are 'live' until you click to expand, so if any other code modifies that array it will be reflected in the logging even if the logging occurs prior to the mutation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was happening because the array was being mutated later in the code. I was not aware that it would affect logging prior to the mutation as pointed out by @skirtle in the comments above.

Answer (score -3):

i guess you should declare your variable first...as an array; then parse it

```
var localCards =[];
localCards =JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localCards'));
```

Comment: How would assigning an empty array that is immediately discarded make any difference?